# How can I find out why Tomcat is using so much memory and stop it?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management, jvm, tomcat7

I'm profiling my webapp using YourKit Java Profiler. The webapp is running on tomcat 7 v30, and I can see that the heap of the JVM is ~30 megabytes, but Tomcat.exe is using 200 megabytes and keeps rising keeps rising.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYovn.png
(On left is how much memory profiler says Java is using, on right is Windows usage of tomcat.exe)

I've tried adding different flags to tomcat, but still the memory usage keeps rising and rising. I've tried precompiling my .jsp files as well in case that helps, but it hasn't.

The flags I've added to tomcat's java flags:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10
-XX:GCTimeRatio=1
```

Tomcat is also running as a windows service if that matters at all.

I need assistance figuring out how to get tomcat to use less memory/know why it's using so much memory. As is is now, it keeps going until it uses the whole system's memory.

Comment: Are you using any native (jni) libraries?

Comment: I don't think so, but we am using a lot of libraries so its possible that one or more of them are using some JNI code. Is there an easy way to debug whether that's the issue or not?

Comment: use jvisualvm to see what is using memory.

Comment: How large does the memory reported by windows grow? Does it level off or just grow indefinitely?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am using YourKit Java Profiler, and it currently says the Java is using ~30-40 megs when it runs and there isn't anything much in memory. But the tomcat process is currently using 250 megabytes of ram at the same time, and just keeps going up while the Java Profiler still says Java memory usage isnt rising.

Comment: @BrettOkken It keeps going up and up while the java memory stays pretty much consistent.

Comment: That is indicative of a native memory leak or at least "retention".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution that I found was to add some flags to the tomcat run.

Not sure which flag it was. I think it might've been the jacob library we were using, or some combo of these flags with that. Hopefully this can help people in the future.

```
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10
-XX:GCTimeRatio=1
-Dcom.jacob.autogc=true
-Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look for memory leaks in your application, or large sessions that live too long and not invalidated. Try to think which functionality holds too many objects for long periods.

Comment: Tomcat has 6 sessions open, none from more than 30 minutes ago. So that doesn't seem to be the memory hog.  (if this is running for 20 hours, I see over a gig of tomcat memory used, but java still profiling as under 200 megs).

Answer (score 0):

You could dump Yor memory and see what is using it. Propably it will be a long list of Your application objects, or strings You unknowingly internalize.

You might use a tool like jvisualvm, or a cool eclipse tool: http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ to do that.

If You do that and still dont know why, then post us what objects are in Your memory....

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, I already did that. There is no leak in the JVM.  For example, my heap according to the JVM would be 20 megs, but the tomcat.exe process would be using 200 megs.